# Use WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) bash command in CMD

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am favorite user of WSL.

Before Restoring my Windows 10 OS, I setup WSL in my Windows and I didn't change any configuration. But One Day, the bash command were executed in CMD immediately. So, If I opened CMD and run a command such as 'ls', then result was the same in bash thing.

However now, I restore my windows and above command excuting no longer occurs. I often use bash commands, so I want to execute bash command in CMD. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by DOS here? WSL is in Windows 10.

Comment: It means terminal. win10 has DOS. you can run WIN + R and run cmd command by 'cmd', and you can excute DOS.

Comment: It's not DOS. It called Command Prompt and it is a shell not terminal. Type this command to execute bash commands: `bash -c "ls"`. Follow [this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference).

Comment: It probably means you also install Msys and MinGW and added the path to the Msys bin directory to you PATH.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin oh, you're right. I checked my removed app list html file (created after windows restoring in 10 version), and found 'MSYS2 64bit' app in list.  very very thanks to Biswapriyo and DavidC.Rankin!!